# Flash/AIR problems with IOS8

Tags: iphone, flash, air, ios8

I have problems with Flash application for IOS8.

I am getting some black space before and after application content, whatever I do I can not remove that black space (atm background is white, so it's not even application space).

I am using Flash CS6 and AIR 15.0.0.349.

Screen shot is here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRh51.png

Comment: I have found solution, I have no idea why this even affects appliction, but I needed to add Default-568h@2x.png splash screen and then it works perfectly fine. For anyone who will need that :)

Comment: If you'd officially answer (in the 'Answer' box) your own question then you'd save people the need to look at a question with zero answers. Thanks.